# Multiple rainbows

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I saw this rainbow the other day – the primary and secondary rainbows are clear:

[image: Rainbows]

but below the primary rainbow there are more rainbow-like fringes (see the zoomed-in version). Is this a rainbow from a sheet of rain further away? Or are there some more complicated optics going on?

[image: More rainbows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should say that the photograph is pretty cool. There are actually quite many reason why that can happen. Do look up the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Variations)

The two primary reasons according to me is -

1. [Supernumerary rainbows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Supernumerary_rainbows). It happens because of interference and cannot be explained using the geometric/ray optics.
2. It can also happen because of refraction of rainbow as it travels through the atmosphere. Note that this particular refraction mainly happens from cones that we don't see (i.e.. the particular arc shape of rainbow is because of the fact we can only see rainbow light cone that's at $40^o$ish angle, while this refraction happen from other angles)

Answer (score 1):

The coloured bands you observed inside the primary rainbow are called supernumerary rainbows.  The second possibility you suggest is the correct one - there is some more complicated optics going on.

Supernumerary rainbows are formed by raindrops that are very nearly the same size.  For any incident angle of sunlight on the raindrop, except the angle that results in minimum deviation, there are two different points on the drop where the the light can be incident which result in the same angle of deviation.  However light incident at these two points travel paths of slightly different lengths before they leave the drop.  This results in interference which gives rise to the supernumerary rainbows.

For a more complete explanation with diagrams please refer to [Supernumerary Rainbows](http://www.atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/supers.htm) and [Supernumerary Bow Formation](http://www.atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/supform.htm).